# FancyBox 3 on mobile - Close popup with a tap instead of a swipe

Tags: mobile, fancybox-3

As you know FancyBox 3, on mobile, allows closing a popup with an up/down swipe.
How can we close it with a tap on the phone's screen instead? If it can be done of course.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, for example, use `clickContent` option:

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
  clickContent : function( current, event ) {
    return current.type === 'image' ? 'zoom' : 'close';
  }
});
```

Using this snippet, clicking images will zoom, but other content - close.

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WEKmoB